# cloud whatsapp api limit conversations per month

Tags: facebook, whatsapp, whatsapi

I'm building a bot using WhatsApp Cloud API,
I'm looking for a way to limit the number of conversations per month per payment, for example, I have a budget of 200USD per month, if I reached it, it will not send more messages/conversations
I checked the API documentation and I didn't see anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight way but You can use [Conversation Analytics API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/business-management-api/analytics#conversation-analytics) from WhatsApp Business Management API, to keep track of the total cost, which provides the cost of conversation as per provided granularity, following is the example of response,

```
{
    "conversation_analytics": {
        "data": [
            {
                "data_points": [
                    {
                        "start": 1643702400,
                        "end": 1646121600,
                        "conversation": 6250,
                        "phone_number": "1919XXXX58X",
                        "conversation_type": "REGULAR",
                        "conversation_direction": "BUSINESS_INITIATED",
                        "cost": 55.0204
                    },
                    ...
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

It will give cost by groping conversation type, conversation direction, and business phone number,

**Conversation Types:**

- `FREE_ENTRY`: Conversations originating from a free entry point.
- `FREE_TIER`: Conversations within the monthly free tier.
- `REGULAR`: Any conversations that did not originate from a free entry point or are above the monthly free tier allotment.

**Conversation Direction:**

- `business_initiated`: Conversations initiated by the business.
- `user_initiated`: Conversations initiated by an end user/customer.

Comment: after using it, If I see that total of conversations it higher from my budget, if I don't send any message back to the user so it's way to "limit/block it"? or each message from user to the "bot/webhook" it count as conversation?

Comment: first, you can block/limit messages from the business side, exactly I am not sure about user-initiated conversation, but here is a demo of [both conversations](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/conversation-types), and [how it works](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/pricing).